# Is it possible to solder wires small 0.5mm to 1mm diameter vias?

Tags: pcb, soldering, via

I need to reprogram the micro-controller on my keyboard. I am new to soldering and would probably buy some equipent and try out on some regular size through holes. I am wondering if it would be possible to solder wires to these tiny vias(looks to be 0.5 - 1 mm diameter.) Maybe it would be helpful with some high flowing solder?

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is a pic of what kind of hole I am talking about.  [image]

Comment: High flowing solder? Isn't that just 60/40 or 63/37 solder? i.e. Normal leaded solder? You would have a lot better luck if you had wires that could fit into those holes rather than just trying to solder to the surface. Like magnet wire (which require you to scrape off some insulation first). 0.5mm and 1mm is enormous though for vias.

Comment: There's no way those are 0.5 mm.

Comment: the keyboard may already have a programming connector

Comment: Are you sure you can't DFU the 32u4 over USB?  You might also consider getting some gold plated sewing needles, preparing them with wire leads and shoving them in the vias for a temporary connection or just holding them with some sideways thumb pressure.  Even ordinary sewing needles might work long enough.

Answer (score 1):

These are pretty big vias. But every via has a pad around it, 0.1-0.2mm around. Use x-acto knife and carefully scratch out the solder mask around it. Then use a lot of rosin-based flux and regular lead-based solder to make the vias solderable. Glue up a 2x5 0.1" header to the edge or your board for easy and robust access by your test leads. Then solder thin magnet wires ( AWG34-36) from your selected vias to the header pins.  Use low-quality magnet wire, so you don't need to scratch ends - the lacquer will come off naturally under hot soldering iron. That's it.

Comment: **No, don't do that**.  Those don't really have much annular ring under the solder mask, and going at it with a knife risks cutting the "shoulder joint" where the hole plating contacts the minimal surface copper.  Instead, use the ability of a pre-tinned *wire* to conduct heat to the hole plating.  Or use silicon insulated wire and a hot air tool to assist the soldering.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I probably was not clear enough that the "scratching" should be done carefully along the SURFACE of PCB. In this case there is very little risk to damage "shoulder joint". And this shoulder is not a "point" or "minimal surface copper", it is the entire "annular ring", so you have to have really assward hands to damage the entire ring.

Comment: The annular rung is probably 6-10 mils wide, so no, there's really not much to work with

Comment: @ChrisStratton, in this particular case you are right. My advice was directed mostly for production-worthy designs that have all vias covered/plugged by solder mask. In this particular pictured board the vias looks opened and huge, so a simple soldering of AWG30 wires should be a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it would be possible to solder wires to these tiny
>   vias

Yes, so long as the vias are not [tented](https://macrofab.com/blog/via-tenting-for-pcb-design/) it is possible.

> Maybe it would be helpful with some high flowing solder?

Regular 60/40 Tin Lead rosin-cored solder wire should work fine. You don't need much, so I recommend using a small diameter, eg. 0.7 mm.

You also need a fine gauge hookup wire which fits in the hole. I use plated 30AWG (0.25 mm) wire wrap wire.

> Any tips are appreciated.

Use a temperature-controlled soldering iron. Make sure the tip is clean and freshly 'tinned' with solder.

Strip the end of the wire and put it though the via. On the bottom side (where the end is poking out) apply solder and soldering iron tip between the wire and hole so they are all touching each other, until the solder melts and goes into the hole (should only take a second). Cut off excess wire.

Comment: Hi, I know it has been pretty long. What If I only have access to one side of the pcb. Will it be ok? Or should I try to desolder all the switches?

Comment: You can solder to the same side that the wire goes into the hole, but you need to leave a bit of bare wire out to solder to. Use a fine chisel iron tip.

Answer (score 0):

Use a thin iron tip, tin the via and the wire (wire wrap or magnet wire. I would tear apart a high density ATA/IDE cable). Once both are tinned, you can tack them pretty easily. Once tacked they will be fragile, so tape or hot glue the wire somewhere so it doesnt get pulled off.

Comment: Pre-tinning the via is likely a mistake more likely to clog it than help when there's no useful annular ring as a pad.  Fluxing would be worthwhile, or if one had SMD paste that could be used to help if it were not heated before the wire.  Pre-tinning the *wire* is of course useful.  But typical ribbon cable is a horrible choice as it is stranded and has an easily and nastily melted insulation.  Good choices would be ultra fine silicone insulated stranded wire, solid wire wrap wire with the insulation kept a millimeter or two from the joint, or enameled magnet wire pre stripped and tinned.